# Is this an Adapter or a Proxy?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, adapter, composition, proxy-pattern

You work on a legacy app which has a static class `UserDataAccess`:

```
public static class UserDataAccess
{
     public static void AddUser(User user) 
     {
        // Insert user into DB
     }
}
```

which is used by a `UserService` class:

```
public class UserService 
{
   public bool AddUser(string firstName, string lastName)
   {
      User user = ...
      UserDataAccess.AddUser(user);
   }
}
```

You need to add unit tests for the `UserService` class, but you cannot modify the `UserDataAccess` (you are not allowed, you do not have access to the DB).

A good solution is to create an interface and inject into `UserService`:

```
public interface IUserDataAccess {
     void AddUser(User user);
}
```

and add an implementation which delegates the call to the static class:

```
public class UserDataAccessProxyOrAdapter : IUserDataAccess 
{
   public void AddUser(User user) { 
       UserDataAccess.AddUser(user);
   }
}
```

My question is, is this a Proxy or an Adapter?

Proxy is supposed to add some functionality. Can the access to the static resource be considered a functionality?

It looks like an Adapter because it adapts the UserDataAccess to be called through the IUserDataAccess interface

What is the correct reasoning and why?

EDIT: This is from this refactoring test, specifically at this step: https://youtu.be/U3QvTaw224o?t=944

Comment: It's more of a Repository design pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is neither an Adapter nor a Proxy design pattern.

Adapter can be dismissed easily because an Adapter's API differs from the API of the object it adapts. Both `IUserDataAccess` and `UserDataAccess` share the same API: `AddUser(User user)`, which rules out the Adapter pattern.

Proxy can be dismissed for the reason mentioned in the OP: there is nothing more than a direct passthrough from `UserDataAccessProxyOrAdapter` to `UserDataAccess`. No remote call, no deferral of instantiation cost, no access control, no additional action taken at all.

We would not want to call this simple example a Proxy design pattern, because that would imply every composition is a Proxy, which would devalue the pattern entirely.

But, do note that proxy is also a general English word; so while it doesn't make sense to name this example a Proxy design pattern, calling it a proxy based on the broader dictionary definition could be valid. I'm not sure whether that was the author's intent or not.

Comment: I was thinking it can be a Proxy maybe that it controls the access (albeit in a very limited way) to the static instance of `UserDataAccess`? A remote proxy for example only serializes calls and deserializes responses.

Comment: There is a powerful incentive to label every (trivial) piece of code with a pattern name: famous names lend legitimacy to the code. Resist this temptation. It incentivizes the devaluation of patterns.

Comment: I was only trying to see if the guy is correct or not. He said it's a Proxy pattern